# Rewriting the initialised value of a variable in the local flash of a arm cortex m4 nrf52

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, cortex-m

I would like to have a variable in flash memory that will retain the value I want after reset.
I know that a variable like this `int test_data = 3` is stored in the .data section of the flash memory and then copied to RAM at run time. I would like, at run time, to modify the value stored in flash memory for variable test_data so that at the next reboot it will load a different default initialised value.

I know it is possible to write the on CPU flash at run time but I don't know how to find the address of the test_variable in flash memory. Can you give me some hints in this direction ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should mention what hardware and libraries do You use.

Comment: Writing to flash is a pain.  You may need to write a whole block, and you may have to explicitly erase it first.  It's an operation that requires some care and planning:(

Comment: 'copied to RAM at run time' - not necessarily.

Comment: By .data section of the flash memory do you mean the `.data` section of the executable? (which you have compiled). If the answer is yes, then I think the question you probably want to ask is `How to rewrite the contents of .data segment in an executable`.

Comment: ..and you may need an intimate relationship with your linker to define a special section for such data so that it can be located in the block to be written, (not something that is at all pleasant:).

Comment: This question has been asked countless times here at SO.  Were those answers not helpful?  (I want to save some value in flash so that it is there next time the mcu boots)

Comment: This would be why picking a MCU with data flash is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing is unlikely to be practical.  Flash memory is word-write, block-erase.  Rewriting a single word is not possible; you have to copy the entire erase-block to RAM, modify the value in the copy, erase the block, then write the entire block from the modified RAM copy. Hoping that the power is not removed during the process.

This may not even be possible is your RAM is smaller that the erase-block size.  Moreover if the SoC executes code from Flash, the block erase is likely to be erasing the code that is executing.

Check your part's documentation but the nRF52840 has relatively small 4Kb pages. A better solution therefore, is to reserve a page for your configuration/initialisation data and read that data in your code and assign it to the appropriate variables on start-up rather than try and rewrite the linker generated code/data.  Better yet, to protect yourself from power-fail use two pages with a sequence number and validation that you write *last*; then on start-up the page with the largest valid sequence number is the one in use.  When you modify the data, you overwrite the older data - that way if it fails before writing the sequence number and validation, you will not have lost all your data.  If the data page is blank, then you use the linker generated initialisation.

This is only an outline of what you need to do - the level of sophistication is up to you.

If your application has hard real-time constraints; you may need to check that the memory bus is not blocked during a page erase/write - this could halt executing of code including interrupt handlers during erase/write and cause you to miss deadlines. Page erase time is up-to is 85ms for nRF52840. If that is an issue, then you are better off perhaps using an external EEPROM.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I would have written if I didn't have to walk our dog:)  Some controllers explictly state that all interrupts must be disabled before attempting a page erase/write:(    I agree that a small EEPROM, maybe SPI or I2C, would be an easier/safer solution.

Comment: some (/many/all) flashes allow you to continue to modify a word, but only in one direction. for example if the block erases to all ones you can (sometimes depending) make some of those zeros then come back later and make more of them zeros, but you cant make them ones again without a block erase.  doubt seriously this helps the OP.  although...hmmm... could design something that works for some number of changes.

Comment: at the end of the day though it is block erase, dedicate a block for this one parameter or you have to do a whole block read-modify-write.

Comment: @old_timer : Stick with _many_, on STM32 devices, you cannot write a word with one or more zero bits (learned the hard way!).  Regarding a whole block for one parameter; what I have done is use the dual-block approach outlined but written to it a serialised associative-map of key+type to value (holding integers, strings and binary-blocks).  At run-time the data is serialised into a data structure, and you access the data by its key (a name string in my case).  That is what I meant when I said it was just a minimal outline.

Comment: @old_timer : Did you mean to add that comment to my answer rather then the question?  The X question to which this is a solution may have been asked, but this is a X-Y problem - I wonder if this precise Y question has been asked - because it is a poor and impractical solution to X.

Comment: "Rewriting a single word is not possible;"  is not a correct statement. I can take 0xFF change it to 0xF3, then chnage it to 0xF0, then chnage it to 0x80...without a block erase...(for some/many flashes)...needed some more verbage...

Comment: @old_timer : I take your point, but as I said that is not universally true either (e.g. STM32) and as you said is not of any practical use for the purpose described in the question.  I think I'll let it stand - it is then at least generally applicable - your comment can serve as information for anyone wanting to exploit such behaviour.  If we regard "rewriting a word" as being able to set _all_ bits to _any_ state, it is true enough,

Comment: In addition, it is often impossible to execute the flash driver code doing the erase from the same bank that is being erased. If you are unlucky the MCU does not have several flash banks. Then the only option is to execute the flash driver from RAM, which is rather questionable practice in most applications. And also very tricky to do when the driver is already written in C and not assembler.

Comment: "Page erase time is up-to is 85ms for nRF52840" One option here is to ensure that the hardware got a big enough backup cap on the supply to keep the MCU supply valid during the programming. Handling mirror flash segments in software is painful.

Comment: @Lundin : I was more concerned about the probability that code executing from flash may be stalled for that period, causing missed interrupts, comms data loss, and failed real-time deadlines.

Comment: @Lundin : ... this part in the reference manual "_The CPU is halted if the CPU executes code from the flash while the NVMC performs the erase
operation_" - similarly for writes (though much shorter duration).